# Cassandra runs OOM when writing

Tags: memory, cassandra, jvm, out-of-memory

I'm wondering why Cassandra is running out of memory on write-only workload.
It's a single node, version 3.10, with default configuration (except added graphite reporter). The machine has 30GB RAM so Cassandra starts with 8GB heap.

I don't know much about Cassandra, but none of the relevant metrics seem suspicious and I don't see anything obvious in the heapdump (just a lot of byte arrays with written data taking space).

Here are the metrics that might be relevant. Notice that heap usage is increasing constantly and soon the process will die due to OOM:
[image: metrics]

(few-sec spikes in GC time are irrelevant, I did force GC several times)

cassandra.yaml: https://gist.github.com/mabn/3b02fe94c819a9dddf3152bcecc00f24

Comment: Can you post your yaml config? this seems related to offheap memory overcommit.

Comment: Added. It's almost the default, with altered paths and address.

Comment: Which cassandra exporter and grafana dashboard did you use to get the metrics?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember how the metrics were captured. I created the dashboard myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use more than 8GB, you should move offheap memtables. This is an important step because will allow you to use more memory, but stick the JVM to the 8GB upper bound, so you won't experience long GC-stop-of-the-world pauses usually triggered with big heaps under pressure.

You move memtables offheap by changing the `memtable_allocation_type` from `heap_buffers` to one of `offheap_buffers` or `offheap_objects`, each one having its own reasons behind. You then tune `memtable_offheap_space_in_mb` to a reasonable value for your system.

In addition, moving memtables offheap frees space in the heap that you can use for key/row caches, improving read performances.

Have a look at these articles:

- [Off-heap memtables in Cassandra 2.1](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/off-heap-memtables-in-cassandra-2-1)
- [The cassandra.yaml configuration file](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html)

Comment: I changed the setting to offheap_objects and set memtable_offheap_space_in_mb to 2GB and it seems fine now. Heap memory usage is not increasing and offheap memory (rss) is stable. One more thing - do you know why it seemed to leak memory when using "heap_buffers"? Size of all memory regions was constant, but heap usage was increasing. Can it be some issue in cassandra 3.x? Or incorrect metrics? Anyway - your suggestion helped - Thanks!

Comment: @mabn GC should guarantee that any process won't leak in the long run. Probably Cassandra adds more and more objects in the heap until the JVM runs out of it. After moving memtables offheap, what's your heap usage?

Comment: Metrics show that heap usage from exceeding old gen limit (at around 6GB) dropped to 1.2GB, size of memtables remained the same (up to 700MB). That's why I'm a bit confused, it does not add up.